# Moment JS Date format to remove minus sign from iso format

Tags: momentjs

I am using moment.js in my application and the expected date format is

```
2017-01-09T17:05:00.000 //Expected Result
```

Where as if i call

```
moment().format()
```

I am getting ISO 8601 format i.e with T and minus sign

```
(2017-01-14T17:05:00-06:00) // Actual result.
```

What should i use to get this format of with .000

Comment: If you are using moment, just specify the format you want it in.

Comment: Thanks. What is the format i need to specify.

Comment: How are you getting ISO date? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/f4cdqwxx/). Works fine for me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I format a date as ISO 8601 in moment.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725019/how-do-i-format-a-date-as-iso-8601-in-moment-js)

Comment: Here OP knows to get ISO 8601 format and looking for alternate format option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISO 8601 is the default representation of moment's format() API. But you can customize it by passing required format pattern.

In your case, `moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS')` will produce what you're looking

> 2017-01-10T11:55:56.621

Find more customization options here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

--

Another option to know, though it works **only for UTC** time : `moment().toISOString()`

> 2017-01-10T06:56:18.465Z

[credit: Rajesh]

Comment: Thanks Bro. Saved my day.

Comment: This is not the idea way. Please check the reference link in my last comment

Comment: @Rajesh Are you refering to `console.log(moment().toISOString())` in your jsfiddle ?

Comment: @JayKumar I meant the comment where I marked this question as duplicate. That post address the correct way i.e. `,toISOString()`

Comment: @Rajesh There's a catch in it. From official docs: `Note that .toISOString() always returns a timestamp in UTC, even if the moment in question is in local mode. This is done to provide consistency with the specification for native JavaScript Date .toISOString(), as outlined in the ES2015 specification.`

Comment: Are you sure? Please check the fiddle. Also if this was true, it would have been a major fuckup by moment team and would have been addressed by now. `.format()` without any format would give utc format, but if you do `.toISOString()` this will return ISO format. If it does not, please raise an issue.

Comment: Yes. It's true and I've quoted the official docs from here. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/ Note that .toISOString() always returns a timestamp in UTC, even if the moment in question is in local mode. This is done to provide consistency with the specification for native JavaScript Date .toISOString(), as outlined in the ES2015 specification.