# Converting a date to a good format that can be sent to database using moment.js

Tags: angular, momentjs

I have trouble with converting my date format into a good one that can be sent to my database. At default I have the current day set in my `dateTimePicker` at 08:00 am. When I want to send it it's format is like this `"2020-12-01T07:00:00.812Z"`.What I try to achieve is `"2020-12-01 08-00"` so not only the format is bad but it's an hour before the chosen time. I tried converting with moment.js but nothing happens.
Here's the code I tried:

```
// form where I can pick the date //
ngOnInit() {
    this.data= this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [],
      dateFrom: [this.setTime(), Validators.required],
      dateTo: [this.getNextWeek(), Validators.required],
      status: [-1],
    });
  }

// function where I try to convert the date to a useable form //

dataModify(object) {
    let formattedObject = {
      id: "",
      dateFrom: object.dateFrom,
      dateTo: object.dateTo,
      status: object.status,
    };

    moment.utc(object.dateFrom).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
    moment.utc(object.dateTo).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');

return formattedObject;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a date as ISO 8601 in moment.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25725019/how-do-i-format-a-date-as-iso-8601-in-moment-js)

Comment: Worth noting that `2020-12-01T07:00:00.812Z` is a UTC date so the timezone will be shifted depending on what timezone your browser is in, so a CET will be one hour ahead of UTC

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you want to save your times in the database as UTC, then convert where required (typically the client).

I'm guessing from your question that you're in GMT+1. You could do the conversion manually, or add moment-timezone:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-timezone

Then you convert like so:

```
// Change 'Europe/Madrid' to whatever timezone  you need
moment(object.dateFrom).tz('Europe/Madrid').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))
```

The nice thing is that if ever you end up having to serve multiple timezones, you can store all the times in UTC then convert where necessary

Comment: `2020-12-01T07:00:00.812Z` is UTC. Thats what the `Z` means

Comment: its like its doing nothing at all, same format

Comment: I know it's UTC. I think Kerk's whole issue is converting it to local time in a format he likes. As for why it's not working kerk, are you importing 'moment-timezone' and not just 'moment'? Otherwise the timezone elements won't work

Comment: yes everything is imported the timezone is good now but the format is still the same and I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but there's no need of momentjs to format date.
You can use this.

```
formatDate = (date) => {
    const _date = new Date(date);
    const day = _date.getDate();
    const month = _date.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = _date.getFullYear();
    return `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
}

formatTime = (date) => {
    const _date = new Date(date);
    const hours = _date.getHours()
    const minutes = _date.getMinutes();
    const seconds = _date.getSeconds();
    return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

toDateTimestamp = (date) => {
    const dateStamp = this.formatDate(date);
    const timeStamp = this.formatTime(date);
    return `${dateStamp} ${timeStamp}`
}
```